# Localising OptionValues

Tags: function-construction

The documentation on `OptionsPattern` leaves me with some unanswered questions. From the example section:

```
Options[f] = {a -> a0, b -> b0}; 

f[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := {x, OptionValue[a]}

f[7, a -> uuu]
(* {7, uuu} *)
```

I don't think using global symbols for the named Options is a great idea so I wonder how to localise them / make sure there isn't going to be any conflict with other definitions in the same document?

```
a=1;
f[7, a -> uuu]
(* {f[7, 1 -> uuu], a0} *)
```

Comment: A somehwat [relevant discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167782/using-strings-instead-of-symbols-good-or-evil/). Since that post, I have changed my views a little, now I use strings as option names somewhat more often than before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some built-in functions use strings as option names:

```
Options[f] = {"AnObscureOption" -> 1};
f[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := {x, OptionValue["AnObscureOption"]}
```

Advantages of this are that the global namespace is not cluttered with extra symbols and they do not have to be write protected but there is a disadvantage in that they are not amenable to `usage` type documentation:

```
"AnObscureOption"::usage = "\"AnObscureOption\" is an obscure option for function f.";
```

> Message::name: Message name "AnObscureOption"::usage is not of the form symbol::name or symbol::name::language.

Comment: Just seen @tchronis's answer -- must type faster!  Guess I'll leave mine for now as I mention a disadvantage of string option names.

Comment: You are very welcome @MikeLimaOscar. Indeed strings cannot have a usage.

Comment: Bigger disadvantage for me is that I can't use auto-completion with them.  (But yes, I also use strings.)

Answer (score 8):

It is normal for option variables to be global and to be given the property `Protected`, which will prevent assigning to them. In your example, you would write

```
Protect[a, b]; Options[f] = {a -> a0, b -> b0};
```

then

```
a = 1;
```

> ```
> Set::wrsym: Symbol a is Protected. >>
> ```

```
a
```

> ```
> a
> ```

```
Attributes[a]
```

> ```
>  {Protected}
> ```

and similarly for `b`.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of protecting option variables that is sacrifice useful names,

I generally use meaningful strings:

```
Options[f] = {"a" -> a0, "b" -> b0};

f[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := {x, OptionValue["a"]}
```

Any objections are very welcomed but this worked for me so far.